# Configure Symfony for use with Memcached

Tags: symfony1, memcached

I have 2 Symfony applications (1 using 1.2.x, another using 1.4.x and both using Propel) that need to share some specific session information. Although I have no experience with memcached, my sense--after some reading--is that it may be able to serve as an external (FAST) repository that each app could read and write to. Unfortunately, I can't find much information about how to use it with Symfony in *any* capacity, much less in the quasi-cache, quasi-messaging server I'm envisioning.

My questions, I suppose, are:

- Am I mistaken in believing that memcached be used in this manner and access by multiple systems?
- How can I configure Symfony to access a memcached repository?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explains one approach fairly well (you don't need the view cache stuff, just the second half about making a singleton available and configuring it):

`http://dev.esl.eu/blog/2009/06/05/memcached-as-singleton-in-symfony/`

**edit:** now 404, but still available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090611145130/http://dev.esl.eu/blog/2009/06/05/memcached-as-singleton-in-symfony/)

You can then use:

```
sfMemcache::getInstance()->set()
```

and

```
sfMemcache::getInstance()->get()
```

(same as the methods [here](http://php.net/memcache)  as sfMemcache subclasses Memcache).

As long as both apps point to the same memcache, you should be able to share data between them like this.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I hadn't seen this article, but this is the direction I took on my own sans extending the `sfMemcache` class that I didn't know existed. This solution seems to tighten things up nicely, so I'm going to move in this direction.